# how to use variable in setcookie()?

Tags: php, session, cookies

I want to pass a variable set by the user to the `setcookie` function. 
I would like to let user change the color of some parts of website. so far the information about color is sent to server with `$_SESSION['colorcode']` and I would like to add it to `setcookie` as well so when the user logs in to the site next time, his/her color is there. 
I've got this code:

```
setcookie(
    'colorcode',
    $_SESSION['colorcode'],
    time() + 60 * 60 * 24 * 30,
    '',
    '',
    false,
    true
);
```

I would like to save the value of variable in cookie, but it works just for the session.
what is wrong? how to do it so the color is there when the user logs in? I'm looking for another way than storing it in database or file.

Comment: Are you setting this cookie on every request? If so, have you considered that $_SESSION['colorcode'] may not be set (or empty)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you read back the value from the cookie at the beginning of the next session? Setting the cookie looks good but I think the last parameters could be omitted.

```
setcookie("colorcode", $_SESSION['colorcode'], time()+3600*24*30, '/');
```

Perhaps even the path (`'/'`) is optional. But this only sets the cookie. You have to read the data back in, when the user returns to your site the next time.

```
if ( !isset($_SESSION['colorcode']) and isset($_COOKIE['colorcode']) ) {
    if ( preg_match('/^#?[0-9a-fA-F]{6}$/', $_COOKIE['colorcode']) ) {
        $_SESSION['colorcode'] = $_COOKIE['colorcode'];
    } else {
        // bad value... delete cookie if you like
    }
}
```

When there is no `colorcode` in the session but the cookie-value exists, then the data is validated and if it's a valid 6 digit hex color code, then the value is inserted into the session. The validation is nessessary because a cookie is data that comes from the user and therefore potentially malicious.

Answer (score 0):

Try to check this:

```
setcookie('colorcode',$_SESSION['colorcode'],time()+60*60*24*30);
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work just fine:

```
setcookie("colorcode",$_SESSION['colorcode'],time()+60*60*24*30);
```

Just make shure you output it in the headers, I guess:

> setcookie() defines a cookie to be
>   sent along with the rest of the HTTP
>   headers. Like other headers, cookies
>   must be sent before any output from
>   your script (this is a protocol
>   restriction). This requires that you
>   place calls to this function prior to
>   any output, including  and
>    tags as well as any whitespace.

Do you get errors?

Comment: no errors. do cookies have to be the very first line in script or could i have in fron of it this? : <?php require_once("classes.php");session_start();?>

Comment: session_start has to be completely first
the cookies should be made before any output is made, which means in short, before any echo or print

Answer (score 0):

since cookie related functionalities (setcookie(), ...) work with HTTP headers, you should user them before any output is sent to client. but this does not mean these functions should appear at the beginning of your code. just make sure no output has been sent. even a single space character at beginning of your file outside of